# Counting Lines in Text Files

Tags: c++, file, text, output, counter

This program splits a file into two files from the main directory and then splices the original file with a new name.

How can I add a counter to output how many lines there are in the new file?

Example: There are 80 lines in this file (placed at the end of the new file)

How might I do so?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void pause();

int main()
{
    char filename[] = "Lab2Test.txt";
    char filenameA[] = "LabTest-FA.txt";
    char filenameB[] = "LabTest-FB.txt";
    char filenew[] = "Lab2Test-NEW.txt";

    ifstream origin(filename);
    ofstream fA(filenameA);
    ofstream fB(filenameB);
    ofstream fnew(filenew);

    if (! origin)
    {
       cout << filename << " could not be opened." << endl;
       return -1;
    }

    string s;
    int i=0;
    while(getline(origin, s))
    {
        if(i % 2 == 1) //odd - write to LabTest-FA
            fA << s << endl;
        else
            fB << s << endl;
        i++;
    }

    fA.close();
    fB.close();

    ifstream fAA(filenameA);
    ifstream fBB(filenameB);

    string s1, s2;
    while(getline(fBB,s1))
    {
        fnew << "A. " << s1 << endl;
        if(getline(fAA,s2))
            fnew << "B. " << s2 << endl;
    }
}

void pause()
{
    cin.sync();
    cout << "Press any key to continue..." << endl;
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int countA, countB;
if(i % 2 == 1) //odd - write to LabTest-FA
{
    fA << s << endl;
    countA++;
}
else
{
    fB << s << endl;
    countB++;
}
i++;
fA << "There are" + countA + "lines in this file"  << endl;
fB << "There are" + countB + "lines in this file"  << endl;

fA.close();
fB.close();
```

If the String concatenation doesn't work like that I'm sorry, has been a while with C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;
counter++;
```

everytime you write to `fnew`.